# A good elementary number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive integers such that $abcd\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{1}{d^2}\right)=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2.$
> Then, prove that  $a+b+c+d $ is not a prime.

My solution with the collaboration of some friends: W.L.O.G, $a\geq b\geq c\geq d$.

Let's assume a quadratic equation with root a,b - $x^2+px+q=0.$
Let's assume a quadratic equation with root c,d - $x^2+p_1x+q_1=0.$

So $abcd=qq_1$. $\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{1}{d^2}=\frac{p^2-2q}{q^2}+\frac{p_1^2-2q_1}{q_1^2}$, then $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=p^2-2q+p_1^2-2q_1$, so $qq_1(\frac{p^2-2q}{q^2}+\frac{p_1^2-2q_1}{q_1^2})=p^2-2q+p_1^2-2q_1$.
Then$\frac{q_1^2(p^2-2q)+q^2(p_1^2-2q_1)}{qq_1}$.
Then after some steps we get $p^2q_1^2-p^2qq_1=p_1^2qq_1-p_1^2q^2$, so $p^2q_1=p_1^2q$.

By substitution $\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}+\frac{(c+d)^2}{cd}$,
$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}=\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{c}$, so $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\text{ or }\frac{d}{c}$.

If $q=q_1$ then $ab=cd$; we get 3 cases $ab=cd$, $ad=bc$, $ac=bd$.
If we take any of the one case by four number lemma
we can write $a=pq$ $b=\gamma s$ $c=ps$ $d=\gamma q$, so $a+b+c+d=pq+\gamma s +ps+ \gamma  q$, then we get $a+b+c+d=(p+\gamma)(s+q)$, hence its not prime

I am looking for  a better solution than this.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Factorize the expression.

Comment: I have used a quadratic equation approach(assuming a and b be roots of one equation and cand be be root of another one) and then using four number lemma i am looking for a different solution from my solution

Comment: @ShamsShawanHoque Please edit your solution in. After that, I'd add in my two-idea solution.

Comment: Quasi's solution was how I approached it. The step of factorizing the expression is motivated by 1/ Well, we have nothing better to do anyway, 2/ Wishful thinking that the terms match up, like $abcd/a^2  = b^2, abcd/c^2 = d^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers such that $L=R$, where
\begin{align*}
L&=abcd\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{1}{d^2}\right)\\[4pt]
R&=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
The equation $R-L=0$ factors as
$$
\frac
{(ab-cd)(ac-bd)(ad-bc)}
{abcd}
=
0
$$
hence at least one of$\;ab-cd,\;ac-bd,\;ad-bc\;$must be equal to zero.

Without loss of generality, assume$\;ab-cd=0$.

Then we get
$$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{d}{b}=\frac{x}{y}$$
where $x,y$ are positive integers with $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

It follows that for some positive integers $s,t$ we have
$$
a=sx,\;\;\;c=sy\\
d=tx,\;\;\;b=ty
$$
so then
$$
a+b+c+d
=
sx+ty+sy+tx
=
(s+t)(x+y)
$$
hence
$a+b+c+d$ is composite.